# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una Instrucción o diálogo emergente en Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Hola cuando utilizo la función print en Python muestra un diálogo que aparece en amarillo. ¿Cómo es posible mostrarlo cuando elabore una función?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta me parece bastante amplia, por favor redúcela a un problema específico. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer lo que buscas son los `DocsStrings` que es para la documentación del código, usarlo es sencillo aquí un ejemplo:

```
def saludo(nombre: str) -> None:
    """Esta función imprime un saludo"""
    print(f"Hola {nombre}")
```

como vemos la función `hola()` recibe un argumento `nombre` que tiene que ser de tipo `str`.

con las comillas `""" """` describimos lo que hace nuestra función.

esta flecha con la palbra `-> None` indica que nuestra función no devuelve nada.

cada vez que pases el mouse sobre la función te mostrara todo lo que documentaste en forma de dialogo emergente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el idle también funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]